# How to Display Pie Chart when clicking on point feature in map?

Tags: geoserver, sql-server, geoext, chart

I want to display pie charts from MS SQL Server database data.

When I click on a point in the map, I wish to see a pie chart over the point.

Can you please tell me how to implement such pie charts?

Do you know any map site that using charts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [GetFeatureInfo](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Control/WMSGetFeatureInfo-js.html) control to retrieve the data from the feature and then use something to render the chart. You can use a JavaScript library (you can start digging from [here](http://webdesignledger.com/resources/13-useful-javascript-solutions-for-charts-and-graphs), I've used highcharts and it's good) ore use an external graph generator like [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart). The last one is the easiest to implement as it's just placing an image tag with a parametrized url.

Comment: BTW, have you looked options reported on any of those [previous questions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=openlayers+chart)?

Comment: do you know any map site that use charts??